# Yii2 timezones: date column changes value depending on format

Tags: php, mysql, yii2, timezone

In my Yii + MySql app, I have a DATE table column like this:

```
start_date DATE
```

And I have a value: `2020-01-01`.

The problem is, when I show the database value '2020-01-01' in a `GridView::widget` I get different values depending on format. For example, this column:

```
[
    'class'     => 'kartik\grid\DataColumn',
    'attribute' => 'start_date',
    'format'    => ['date', 'php:d/m/Y G:i:s e P'],
],
```

shows `31/12/2019 23:00:00 UTC +00:00`. **Absolutely wrong**, as it should be '2020-01-01' (it's a DATE column, not DATETIME).

While this column:

```
[
    'class'     => 'kartik\grid\DataColumn',
    'attribute' => 'start_date',
],
```

shows `2020-01-01`. **This is the correct value**.

I know MySql DATE column assumes time as 00:00:00 and I read in some (old) docs that Yii2 assumes all dates in database are UTC, which in my opinion is wrong.

My timezone configuration at different levels is like this:

- Unix server: GMT+1 (CET)
- PHP (php.ini): not set
- Yii2 (main.php): 'timeZone' => 'Europe/Madrid' (tested also with Europe/London)
- MySql: @@global.time_zone / @@session.time_zone = SYSTEM
- MySql: `select timediff(now(), utc_timestamp())`: 01:00:00

How can I tell Yii2 that database values are in GMT+1 as the server is, or that database values are timezone agnostic?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need to change [`Formatter::$defaultTimeZone`](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-i18n-formatter#$defaultTimeZone-detail) to `Europe/Madrid` - this should specify that date passed to formatter is not UTC but `Europe/Madrid`.